# Time Series - Approach for Identifying Square Wave-type Signals

Tags: python, time-series, fft, distribution, curve-fitting

I am trying to a way to find an approach to filtering out signals that have a pattern like the one below.

The pattern can be described having square waves, often having a constant fluctuating value +-1, +-2, or +-0 over numerous time periods. The signal will often drop within 5-100 std dev instantaneously and then remain at a constant rate for a very short period of time, then shoot back up again. These types of signals can have single or multiple varying lengths of square waves, but always exhibit a square wave in the signal.

[image]

Data for this signal:

```
y = array([  8.,   8., 173., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130.,130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130., 130.,130., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131.,131., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131., 131.,172., 172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 173.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172.,172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 173.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 173., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 173., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172., 172.,172., 172., 172., 172., 172.])
```

I need to find an approach that can help me cluster out or filter out these signals of about 3000 signals. I've tried the following and have had very mixed results:

- Univariate Time Series Clustering w/ TSLearn and DTW python packages on a number variance-related features (mixed results)
- Multivariate Clustering with K-Means, KNN, etc (can often assign multiple clusters for an individual signal. Rule is one bucket for one signal, not multiple buckets)
- Conditional logic that finds subsequences in arrays, hoping to find the square waves (I can't do anything with this because half the length of a good signal can be equal to half the length of the important part of the signal; the square wave)
- Kernel Distribution Estimation (I have other signals that have the same distribution as this signal, so I cannot filter these out based on ranking/clustering of coefficients)

Can you recommend other approaches that would help me identify this type of signal from a group of other signals? If your approach is on Fourier Transformations, can you provide an example of how I might use it to filter out this signal from a group of other signals?

Comment: Given the discrete nature of your response, you might consider [Walsh/Hadamard analysis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WalshFunction.html) instead of Fourier analysis of your data.

Comment: @pjs, can you elaborate how I can use this as an approach to filtering out for this signal across other signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def first_der(df):
  y = df.NREVS.values
  x = df.cum_int.values

  dy=np.diff(y,1)
  dx=np.diff(x,1)
  yfirst=dy/dx
  return yfirst

def zero_runs(yfirst):
    # Create an array that is 1 where a is 0, and pad each end with an extra 0.
    iszero = np.concatenate(([0], np.equal(a, 0).view(np.int8), [0]))
    absdiff = np.abs(np.diff(iszero))
    # Runs start and end where absdiff is 1.
    ranges = np.where(absdiff == 1)[0].reshape(-1,2)
    return yind
  
def square_finder(yfirst, yind, df):

  xmax = yind.shape[0]  #max value in first position where y_first can be indexed
  ymax = yind.shape[1] #max value in second position

  thresh = 4
  for i in range(0,xmax):
    if yind[i][1] < len(yfirst):
      if ((yfirst[yind[i][1]] > 5) | (yfirst[yind[i][1]] < -5)):
        #if ((yfirst[yind[i-1][1]+1] > 3) | (yfirst[yind[i-1][1]+1] < -3)):
        zeros = yind[i][1] - yind[i-1][1] - 2
        if zeros >= thresh:
          df['category'] = 'square'
        else:
          pass
      else:
        pass
    else:
      pass
  return df
```